# find column names corresponding to least value of each row in R

Tags: r

i have to extract column names corresponding to least 10 values for each row of a data frame and print it in new data frame.Can anyone help me do that?

my data frame looks like this:(15 x 15 matrix)

```
    > head(yt)
        V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12  V13  V14  V15 
    1    0  966 1513 2964 1149  927 1611 1510  390  466 1820 1718  504 1179  
    2  966    0 2410 1520 1817  729  686  290 1823  168 2027  172 1610 1500 
    3 1513 2410    0  604  481 2742 1833  826  214 1618 1712  567  544 1313 
    4 2964 1520  604    0  595 1289 1446  466 1139  430  428  201  452 1574 
    5 1149 1817  481  595    0  494  550 2641  765  934 1813 1516  378 1363 
    6  927  729 2742 1289  494    0 1279 1197 2956  299  888  491 1408 1432
```

for each of the 15 rows i would like to know column names for least 10 columns

i know which.min gives least column name for each row but can you let me know other ways of computing least 10 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `order` function will give the ordering of a vector. So the first value of its result corresponds to the index of the smallest value in the vector. The second to the index of the second smallest etc. Using it in a function and using the `apply` function we can apply it to all rows. The apply function's result is column wise, which you probably don't want, so the transpose is taken over the result.

```
first_10 <- function(x) order(x)[1:10]
t(apply(dat, 1, first_10))
```